# How to disable LowerCaseFilter when using SnowballAnalyzer in Lucene 3.0.2?

Tags: java, lucene, case-sensitive

I realise that 3.0.2 is an old version of Lucene but if I have Java code as follows:

```
int nGramLength = 3;
Set<String> stopWords = new Set<String>();
stopwords.add("the");
stopwords.add("and");
...
SnowballAnalyzer snowballAnalyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, "English", stopWords);                  
ShingleAnalyzerWrapper shingleAnalyzer = new ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(snowballAnalyzer, nGramLength);
```

Which will generate the frequency of ngrams from a particular a string of text without stop words, how can I disable the LowerCaseFilter which forms part of the SnowBallAnalyzer? I want to preserve the case of the ngrams generated so that I can perform various counts according to the presence / absence of upper case characters in the ngrams.

I am something of a Lucene newbie. And I should add that upgrading the version of Lucene is not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snowball analyzer is a convenience class for using `SnowballFilter`. `LowerCaseFilter` is baked into the code.

Just copy the `SnowballAnalyzer` source and remove line 103 `streams.result = new LowerCaseFilter(streams.result);`

Comment: 'baked'? I like that. Do you know where the code can be obtained from?

Comment: If you use Maven with Eclipse right-click press F3 when your cursor is over the analyzer and it will download the source code. If not using Maven, you can still get the sources.jar file here: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22lucene-snowball%22

Comment: For the record I was looking at the source through GrepCode: http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-snowball/3.0.2/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.java/?v=source